# Why Owin CookieAuthentication doesn't validate user ID in DB?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

As mentioned there: [Why do ASP.NET Identity logins from one site get shared with different websites on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589429/understanding-asp-net-identity)

> The OWIN authentication middleware will not check the database if there is a valid cookie in an incoming request. It will simply use the presented encrypted claims (username, possibly roles and other) in the cookie

So as far as I understand I could have workflow like this:

- Register new user with username **test_auth**
- Sign in as **test_auth**
- Remove **test_auth** form DB

And after removing **test_auth** from DB it will pass checking by **Authorize** attribute, so I don't have **test_auth** user in my DB, but it could use pages, protected with **Authorize** attribute.

I'm confused why it implemented in that way. Is it really secure?

Comment: @developer, code markdown is for use with code only - you completely destroyed that list. Also you left a `enter code here` in there.... please take more care when editing.

Comment: @OGHaza okay sorry, i'll take care next time..

Comment: The cookie will stay there for the duration of the authentication session. Your described scenario will work long term only if you make the cookie persistent, i.e. mark "remember me" checkbox.

Comment: @0leg. Yeah, I understand this moment. But it possible in some cases(if you checked "Remember me" as you mentioned), so my question is: is it safe enough?

Comment: Any time you allow persistent authentication cookie there is a security risk.  Storing it on the browser file system is the issue.  The cookie itself is protected from tampering by encryption and hashing, so there is no need to verify the test_auth user name in the cookie.  The only way to verify it against the database is to ask for the password again.

Comment: What the hell. More than year and no proper answer, seems ASP guys don't care.

Comment: 0leg: Could you link to any documentation about the encryption and hashing mechanism OWIN CookieAuthentication are using? I want to be sure how the security works by default, some improvements will probably be necesarry in order to prevent cookie tampering.