# Why do I keep getting HTTP 403 error on shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 app, developed under .NET 4.6 and MVC 5.2.3 that works 100% when I debug it in Chrome and Edge on my machine. When I deploy to shared hosting at my ISP, it gives the following error on every request after the very first one, which succeeds and shows the login page.

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Then if I clear a cookie called `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` from Chrome, then the next request succeeds, but the cookie is back and all subsequent requests fail in the same manner.

I am not using application state in any of my own code, and the only packages I have added to those that come with the standard VS2015 project template are:

```
AutoMapper
elmah.corelibrary
Elmah.Mvc
Unity
Unity.Mvc5
```

If I've done this correctly, when I check for cookies in Edge, there no such cookie, only the `__RequestVerificationToken`, which plays no role (outside the scope of this question) in Chrome.

**NOTE:** I have now changed hosting providers, and instead of get a 403 on nearly every request since after the first since app startup, I now get redirected to my login page about every 1 to 2 minutes. It looks like one provider is handling my lack of auth better, but have a strong suspicion that both problems are due to loss of session. This is probably due to limited resources on shared hosting, so I've tried moving to storing session on SQL Server but it makes no difference, and Elamh shows no errors, so I don't know if my session move worked.

Comment: Other apps on hosting works?

Comment: No, @SamuelTulach, I have no other hostings nor app,, and since changing hosts has mitigate this problem, as my note at the bottom pf the question says, I can't afford to take that one aoo down and try another one.

Comment: Regarding your next attempt at hosting, did you set a MachineKey in your web.config?  Most shared hosting load balances your site.  Without setting a machine key, IIS generates one itself.  If two servers each generate thier own machine key, they cannot read each other's encrypted cookies.  Thus, you appear to be logged out.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations Please note that authentication and session management are two complete and distinct things in a web app.  Getting "logged out" is not related to session.

Comment: @Tommy Thanks for the notes on session and login; I've never been quite clear if login was a special part of session or 100% separate. I did have a machine key that didn't make any difference on the 1st host, but I think I lost it on a rollback somewhere. I'll check and add one again.

Comment: NP professor, let me know how your testing goes when you get a chance to get to it!

Answer (score 1):

I  think you are using the new dotnet core Cookie middleware. This middleware encrypts your session data inside the cookie value.

The problem is that the encryption/decryption is done based on a key which is unique per application-host (based on machine key). So if your request lands on a different instance than where your session cookie was encrypted, it is unable to decrypt your cookie, and thus thinks you are not authenticated!

You can change this behavior by implementing a different backing store (like redis or sql server).

Read the documentation on how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

Comment: This sounds pretty much like a shot in the dark. Where does the OP say they're using Core or multiple servers?

Comment: @CodeCaster By what you describe it looks a lot like the issue i had. Can you tell me: how does your cookie value look in the browser? is it a short Identifier or does this look like a long encrypted string? And how did you configure your Cookie/session authentication in MVC5?

Comment: @CodeCaster, good point on me using Core, since I especially stated I was using .NET 4.6 and MVC 5.2.3, but I also stated I am on shared hosting, which means I am but 1 website of hundreds on one IIS "instance", but how many servers that "instance" is shared over nobody knows.

Comment: You have a point about multiple servers, though I did say I wasn't using core, and I did say that I have tried switching to a new SQL Server backing store.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the cookie name it sound like the server is configured to use cookie authentication and you are using the default cookiename.

This type of authentication decrypts the cookie based on machine key. And since its a hosted environment on a shared machine it is decrypted in the same way as other application, and other applications are probably using the same default cookiename.

This would mean that the authentication is interfering with the other applications thats why you get the 403 even if I am not fully sure of the exact point of error.

The solution to this is setting a different Cookiename in Startup.Auth.cs

You have a related question here with code example of setting cookie name: [Why do ASP.NET Identity logins from one site get shared with different websites on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589429/why-do-asp-net-identity-logins-from-one-site-get-shared-with-different-websites)

Hope that solves your issue.